# Shopware 6: How to 'tap in' to the update method of an entity?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have tried to find a solution, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong term.

I want to modify an Entity (a custom one) when the update for the DAL is called. But I cannot seem to find what method to implement in my Entity.
What I'm looking for is a kind of 'hook'. I thought that maybe I could create a Service and look for a specific event, but there is only events for Products, Categories etc.
Should I implement an event for my Entity or is there something more general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general `EntityWrittenEvent` that is dispatched whenever the DAL writes an entity. When you want to listen to the written event for a specific entity you can do so by creating a [EventSubscriber](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber) that listens on the `{entity_name}.written` event.

The event classes for Products and Categories etc. are basically just constants for the same event, but the event name is generic. E.g instead of using `ProductEvents::PRODUCT_WRITTEN_EVENT` in your event subscriber you can listen on `product.written` as that is internally the same.

Also take a look at the [official docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/using-database-events#event-overview) there too `product` is used as an example, it works the same way for every entity (even custom ones).

Comment: Thank you! I have looked at that documentation page a few times - and thought it only related to products. Perhaps an update adding a paragraph saying it applies to all entities could be helpful